# Unable to upload files larger than 1Mb or so in Hostgator

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, hosting

So I am trying to upload files larger than 1Mb using Php but they are uploaded in my MySQL database as empty files...I checked the php.ini file and its limit is 64Mb. Files are being uploaded to database if they are less than 1Mb and are also saved in a temporary folder...

```
     post_max_size  64M 64M
     upload_max_filesize    64M 64M
```

I am on Hostgator hosting and the website in question is www.takebooks.in . I talked with the support team and they said everything was fine on their end and problem was with my code...
I dont think that this is related to my php code...also only thing I think might be affecting is (which is fine):

```
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
      Photo: <input type="file" name="photo" required="required"><br>
```

At my database the datatype for file is mediumblob which permits me around 16Mb.
I am confused where is the issue?
This the error log while I was trying to upload the file...

```
[14-Jul-2014 01:08:50] PHP Warning:  fopen() [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/basicssc/public_html/takebooks.in/listitem.php on line 34
[14-Jul-2014 01:08:50] PHP Warning:  fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/basicssc/public_html/takebooks.in/listitem.php on line 35
[14-Jul-2014 01:08:50] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/basicssc/public_html/takebooks.in/listitem.php on line 37
[14-Jul-2014 01:08:50] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/basicssc/public_html/takebooks.in/listitem.php:34) in /home/basicssc/publi
```

Comment: Do not mark duplicate unnecessarily with other questions; before posting this questions I have read them thoroughly and they are not relevant to my issue...

Comment: Does the upload time out ? Have you tried increasing `max_execution_time` ?

Comment: max_execution_time 30 30

Comment: Chrome shows it being uploaded to 100% and then page process the upload to database where you see the file as empty...so no problem with upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG it was a silly mistake as you can see the max file limit in my html is

```
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
```

which is arround 2MB so need one more zero...

```
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000000">
```

this fixed it! Now its 20Mb...